# MariaDB: varchar == text?

Tags: mariadb

I have Maria DB 10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 and entered the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `cache` (
  `ckey` varchar(750) NOT NULL,
  `dtime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(60000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY
```

The result was:

```
#1163 - Storage engine MEMORY doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns
```

Where does it find a Blob or Text here? Does MariaDB convert large varchar columns into text automatically? The docu says, that varchar can be up to 65,535 bytes of size.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond a certain size (255?), MEMORY turns `VARTEXT` and `VARBINARY` into `TEXT` and `BLOB`.

Bottom line is that you cannot use that big a field with the `MEMORY` engine.

Comment: I could not find that in the MariaDB documentation. Where did you find that information?